# How to properly use contextual filter on group content fields

Tags: views

On my homepage, I created a view for group contents with relationship on "Group content" and "Group". I want to create a contextual filter that when I search on the exposed filter, results will be displayed on new page.

I have an exposed filter of "Category" and "Region" and without contextual filter the result displays on the same page.

I tried filtering with field "Name" as "Display a summary", and I get this:

[image: Display on summary]

But when I manually click on any item and check its URL, i'm getting this:

```
http://localhost:8888/drupal-8.2.3/home/Mozilla%20123?field_trade_type_job_target_id=All&field_region_business_target_id=All
```

And I can't search to other items anymore since I am on a filter specific path, in the example above, `/Mozilla%20123?`

I tried another field name, "Category" and I get this, since the 3 given examples are in the same category:

[image]

`18` is a taxonomy path. When I manually click the content, I am directed to:

```
http://localhost:8888/drupal-8.2.3/home/18?field_trade_type_job_target_id=All&field_region_business_target_id=All
```

with this content:

[image: Category]

This image supposed to be what I want to achieve in the first place when I click search on the exposed filter in the homepage.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I found the solution to my issue.

These are the steps I come up and followed.

1. Add taxonomy term relationship to the view.
2. On the Contextual filter, search "Name" with taxonomy as description
3. Under "WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS IN THE URL OR A DEFAULT IS PROVIDED", tick "Specify validation criteria"
4. Choose the desired vocabulary.
5. Save and test in the Preview section.